# Proof Explanation in Hatcher, Theorem 3.43

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, manifolds, homology-cohomology, solution-verification

Here is the link to the book: http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf

In Theorem 3.43, checking the commutativity of the diagram is left to the reader. The first square commutes trivially, but I have no idea of the second and the third  squares. I also can't see where the $[B]$ in the diagram came from. Thanks in advance.

Edit. This theorem is a generalization of a theorem in Bredon's *Topology and Geometry*, Theorem VI.9.2, and the proof is similar too. I understood the proof in Bredon's but I think it is nontrivial to apply the same proof directly.

Comment: The map $[B]\smallfrown $ is defined in theorem 3.30.

Comment: @OliverJones But $[B]$ shouldn't just be an arbitrary fundamental class, in order to diagram become commutative. Also Theorem 3.30 is stated for a manifold without boundary, while $B$ is a manifold with boundary.

Comment: At the beginning of the proof of theorem 3.43, the author says that the cap product extends to relative cohomology. I'm not sure what you're saying concerning the map $[B]\smallfrown$. It is defined, right?

Comment: @OliverJones Yes. But such a map is not uniquely determined, so I think the $[B]$ in the diagram must be determined by something. Hovever, I have no idea.

Comment: I'm not following you. What do you mean that the map is not uniquely determined?

Comment: @OliverJones I was meaning that I think there should be a relation between two classes $[M]$ and $[B]$ in the proof, to check the continuity of the diagram.

Comment: @OliverJones Oh I think I found an explanation in p.358 of Bredon's book: http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/~ralph/math215b/Bredon.pdf

Comment: I was looking for a reference as well. Yes, Q3 of Bredon's book explains how to choose the orientation class $[B]$. Is it clear now?

Comment: @OliverJones Yes Now I should have to check commutativity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I just tried to work through this so here's my attempt at commutativity. Actually as Bredon points out, the square only commutes up to sign, but that's actually good enough.

We asume that $A$ and $B$ keep the orientation of $\partial M$.
Pick $[\phi] \in H^k(M, A)$, where $\phi \in C^k(X)$ is zero on $C_k(A)$. I'll assume that the fundamental classes $[M] \in H^k(M, \partial M), [A] \in H^k(A, \partial A)$ and $[A] \in H^k(A, \partial A)$ are represented by cycles $\mu \in C^k(M), \beta \in C^k(A)$ and $\alpha \in C^k(A)$ respectively.

We observe that $\alpha + \beta$ represents $[\partial M]$ : First note that $[\partial \left( \alpha + \beta\right)] = [\partial A] - [\partial A]$ (the orientations of $\partial A$ and $\partial B$ differ by a sign) so $[A] + [B]$ indeed represent a class in $H_{n-1}(\partial M)$. Second, this class restricts to a local orientation of $\partial M$ on any interior point of $A$ or $B$, so by the isomorphism $H_{n-1}(\partial M) \cong H_{n-1}(\partial M , \partial M - x)$ for $x \in \partial M$ this class represents $[\partial M]$.

We denote the lower horizontal map in the relevant square $\delta$. Now lets take a look at the result of going down first and then right
$$
\delta ([M] \frown [\phi]) = [ \partial (\mu \frown \phi ) ] = [ (-1)^k (\partial \mu \frown \phi - \mu \frown \delta \phi) ] = (-1)^k  [ \partial M ] \frown [\phi]
$$
(since $\delta \phi = 0$). Now we consider going right first and then down (in two steps). The first two maps only consist of restricting $\phi$, first to $C_k(\partial M)$ and the to $C_k(B)$, so the result of this map is
$$
[B] \frown \left[\phi|_{C_k(B)}\right] = [\beta \frown \phi] = [(\alpha + \beta) \frown \phi] = [\partial M] \frown [\phi]
$$
And we are done.